# Sharing auto_increment `id` and table relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
`brands`        (`id`, `name`)
`categories`    (`id`, `name`)
`products`      (`id`, `name`, `brand_id`, `category_id`)
```

There are more columns, though these are the only ones relevant to the issue.

I want all three tables to share the same `auto_increment` `id` (ie. make the `id` unique cross the three tables). The latter can be solved easily by using a common table referencing to an appropriate table:

```
`entries` (`id`, `name`, `type_id`)
```

The problem is that in the original scenario all tables have foreign constraints:

- if category is deleted, set NULL products.category_id
- if brand is deleted, cascade products.brand_id
- if product is deleted, cascade all reviews

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could do this in MySQL would be to create one table with a single `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, insert into this table, get the last inserted ID (how exactly you do this depends on which MySQL client library you are using) and then use this ID when inserting the row into one of the other tables.

(It's a shame PostgreSQL isn't more popular than MySQL, since it supports exactly this feature out-of-the-box: you'd only have to share one sequence object between tables.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want a unique identifier across projects but denseness or monotonicity don't appear to be requirements ... Would UUID () suffice?